# Conditionally remove duplicates from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array that looks like this

```
[
    {
        topic: 'Topic 1',
        person: { ... },
        unit: 'ABC-DEF'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Topic 1',
        person: { ... },
        unit: 'ABC'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Topic 1',
        person: { ... },
        unit: 'ABC-123-DEF'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Topic 2',
        person: { ... },
        unit: 'ABC-123'
    }
]
```

"units" are organisational units in my company. If there are duplicates **by topic** I want to keep only the object **with the shortest unit** and remove all others. So the example from above becomes:

```
[
    {
        topic: 'Topic 1',
        person: { ... },
        unit: 'ABC'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Topic 2',
        person: { ... },
        unit: 'ABC-123'
    }
]
```

I already took a look at uniqBy from lodash but how can I make sure that only the duplicate with the shortest unit stays in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uniqBy` keeps the first item it finds, so just sort by `unit.length` before filtering:

```
_.uniqBy(_.sortBy(data, x => x.unit.length), 'topic')
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this question is already answered, I tried it using native javascript APIs (in case someone wants to do it without using lodash)-

I used `sort` to sort the array according to `shortest unit`.

And then grouped them by `topic` and chose first item as item with shortest unit (because it was sorted in first step).

Checkout this code -

```js
var finalData = [];
var data = [
    {
        topic: 'Topic 1',
        person: {  },
        unit: 'ABC-DEF'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Topic 1',
        person: { },
        unit: 'ABC'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Topic 1',
        person: { },
        unit: 'ABC-123-DEF'
    },
    {
        topic: 'Topic 2',
        person: { },
        unit: 'ABC-123'
    }
];

data.sort((item1, item2) => {
    return item1.unit.length - item2.unit.length;
}).reduce(function(groups, item) {
    if (!groups[item.topic]) {
        finalData.push(item);
        groups[item.topic] = true;
    }
    return groups;
  }, {});
  
console.log(finalData);
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I fixed a couple of mistakes in your code, hope you don't mind.